# Account name linked to an opportunity

Tags: opportunity, account

I've been trying to get the account name linked to opportunity through query.

CODE:

```
query = "SELECT Id, Name, Phone, AccountId FROM Opportunity"
    fileList = ""
    i = 0
    fileList = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/queryAll/', {'q': query})
    for x in fileList['records']:
        fileId = fileList["records"][i]["Id"]
        fileName = (fileList["records"][i]["Name"])
        accId = fileList["records"][i]["AccountId"]
        query1 = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id='%s'"%(fileList["records"][i]["AccountId"])
        fileList1 = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/queryAll/', {'q': query1})
        accountName = fileList1["records"][0]["Name"]
        print(fileId,"  ",accountName," ",accId )
        i += 1

    return data
```

This is working fine.But takes a lot of time in the background because of the extra request for getting account name.Is there any other way to get the account name?

Comment: You can get the Account name for any opportunity by querying Account.Name on a SOQL that runs on the Opportunity object. `SELECT Account.Name FROM Opportunity`

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo Thanks for the response. But,
`AccountName = (fileList["records"][i]["Account.Name"])`
is throwing a KEYERROR

Comment: This works fine: `AccountName = fileList["records"][i]["Account"]["Name"]`

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
query = "SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity"
    fileList = ""
    i = 0
    fileList = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/queryAll/', {'q': query})
    for x in fileList['records']:
        fileId = fileList["records"][i]["Id"]
        fileName = (fileList["records"][i]["Name"])
        accountName = fileList1["records"][i]["Account"]["Name"]
        print(fileId,"  ",accountName," ",accId )
        i += 1

    return data
```